# Default method for asmx web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

So I have a web service method that lives at:

`mysite.com/mywebservice.asmx?op=GetOrders`

Is there any way that I can automatically call the `GetOrders` method if they just navigate to:

`mysite.com/mywebservice.asmx`

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [urlMappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228302%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Web.Config.

> Defines a mapping that hides the real URL and maps it to a more
>   user-friendly URL.

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
  <clear />
  <add url="mysite.com/mywebservice.asmx" mappedUrl="mysite.com/mywebservice.asmx?op=GetOrders" />
</urlMappings>
```

But I think this will effect your other methods, like if you call a `mysite.com/mywebservice.asmx?op=SomeOtherMethod` this would take you `GetOrders`, I am not sure about it, but you can try.